# How do I remove or disable event listeners in React that are initialized by react-dom?

Tags: reactjs, performance, event-listener, react-dom

I noticed that a React app I've been working on has suddenly become slower. After some investigating, I can see that there are many unused event listeners active.
[image]

The functionality of my app isn't using any of these. Drilling deeper, it looks like most of them are dispatched from react-dom.
[image]

The only reference to react-dom is in my Main.jsx file using createRoot:

```js
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);
```

I can't find any resource detailing this issue. Does anyone know how to disable these?

I tried drilling down to see if I was adding these event listeners in my project code. I was expecting to be able to disable these, but cannot find any way to do so.

Comment: Is your code using `event-listeners`? if so, please update your post with a working code example.

Comment: My project has a few eventlisteners I manually added, but none of those are relevant to this issue.

Comment: In my case, I restarted Chrome and noticed a speed improvement. While the event listeners listed here are excessive in my opinion, I don't believe they were the reason for the performance issue I was experiencing.

Comment: It's okay, if not using too many event-listeners then it doesn't affect to your code anymore. Maybe it was the excessive working part of Chrome.